# Spring setting property from code while having bean's name

Tags: java, spring

in short... my aspect catches an invocation (by @Before). 
I can get from joinpoint the bean's name

```
 myapp.dao.BookRepository
```

in spring xml it looks like that:

```
<bean id="bookRepo" class="myapp.dao.BookRepository">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

All I want to do is to set that property like below in invoked method.

Locally in that class I can do it like that (first line in method body):

```
@Override
public Collection<Book> getAll() {
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource); // this line I want to move to the aspect
    return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Book", new RowMapper<Book>() {
        public Book mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return extractBook(rs);
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately I had to do it in that aspect. It should also be said that I have many other classes which inherit that method, so I can't just cast it without large switch (check bean name and cast to apropriate class).
 Please let me know if something like this is possible in Spring.

Comment: Why are you not injecting `jdbcTemplate` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are not using Aspects where you shall! It doesn't seem a problem which shall be handled by AOP to me.

Do you have multiple data-sources? If you have just one data-source just inject the datasource in Spring XMLs, and configure `JdbcTemplate` there.

If you have multiple data-sources, don't use a `jdbcTemplate` as field in your class, otherwise you will face strange bugs in concurrent environment, because each thread sets its own data-source in a single `jdbcTemplate` and....